# What is the different vs array.push() and array = [...array, newItem]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have seen some YouTubers not use `array.push()` to add items to an array but rather do something like:

```js
let item = 3
let array = [1, 2];

array = [...array, item]; // Why not use array.push()?
```

Is there any difference between the two methods and which one should i use?

Comment: Try `let array2 = array;` and then `push` or `[...]`, then compare `array` and `array2` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: `[...array, item]` - this will: 1. create a new array. 2. copy (shallow) all the items from `array` into this newly created array. 3. add the `item` in the newly created array. Difference lies in the creation of the new array as compared to manipulating the existing array incase of `push()` method.

Comment: Has anyone tested this form a performance point of view? Is array.push() actually more efficient or is it the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Push: Use push when you want to add data in the existing array and don't want to cra**

When you use the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method, you are adding the element to the existing one i.e not creating a new array.

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
> returns the new length of the array. - MDN

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const returnValue = arr.push(6);

console.log(arr);
console.log(returnValue)
```

**Spread Syntax: Use spread syntax if you want to add elements in new array(it can be from spread or can add more new elements also) but will create a new array `[]`**

This is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

> Spread syntax (...) allows an iterable such as an array expression or
> string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for
> function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an
> object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more
> key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

```js
let array = [1, 2];
let item = 3

result = [...array, item];
console.log(result === array);
```

In the above snippet you are creating a new `array` and assigning values `1, 2` then you are using spread syntax to spread it into a new array. You can also add new elements also like `item` whose value is `3`.

Answer (score 1):

array.push manipulates the existing array. The latter makes a new copy with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

Array push is used to push items kn exisiting array but if we want a copy of an element of an array as a new array variable- you can use […array] operator.